# Changing what the reference variable refers to

Tags: java, arrays, reference

Say I want to change what the reference variable a refers to. And I have:

```
  int[] a = {2,3,4,5,6,7};
  int[] b = {6,4,3,7,8,9,3,10,1};
  a = b;
```

I want a to now refer to the array at the memory location of b. This doesn't work because now it saying that a equals the memory address of b. Is there a way to get a to refer to the array that is at the memory address instead of just a equaling the address at which b is at?

Comment: It really unclear what you're asking. You've assigned b to a, so they both now refer to the same array, and the array you initially assigned to a is available to the garbage collector.

Comment: In your example, `a` is assigned the value of `b` so `a` now refers to the same array as `b`. Are you asking how to *copy* an array?

Comment: Basically I'm asking because this is a simpler example of something else I am trying to do. It answered my question that now b is assigned to a which is exactly what I want. Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 2):

In Java we don't speak of "memory addresses" (this is not C!), we have *references* to objects, with pass-by-value semantics. So answering your question: the `b` variable is *already* referring to the array, conceptually it's incorrect to say that `a` equals the memory address of `b`. For further clarification, take a look at this [post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141834/how-is-a-java-reference-different-from-a-c-pointer) that explains how a Java reference is different from a C pointer.

Comment: This notion that java "references" aren't like c pointers is rather silly, IMHO.

Comment: @BrianRoach _most_ of the time they might be the same thing, but not _always_ - it's an implementation detail. See the link at the end of my answer